# Ошибка при применении аннотации и рефлексии

Tags: java, аннотации, рефлексия

Пример из книги Шилдта:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;


@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@interface  MyAnno{
    String str();
    int val();
}

class Meta {
    @MyAnno(str = "Two params", val = 19)
    public static void myMeth(String str, int i){
        Meta ob = new Meta();

        try {
            Class<?> c = ob.getClass();
            Method m = c.getMethod("myMeth", String.class, int.class);
            MyAnno anno = m.getAnnotation(MyAnno.class);
            System.out.println(anno.str() + " " + anno.val());
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myMeth("Test", 10);
    }
}
```

Выводится ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Meta.myMeth(Meta.java:21) 
    at Meta.main(Meta.java:29)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RetentionPolicy` поменяйте на `RUNTIME`:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface  MyAnno{
    String str();
    int val();
}
```

В [доках](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html) про это сказано:

> `CLASS` Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler
> **but need not be retained by the VM at run time**.
>
> `RUNTIME` Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the
> compiler and **retained by the VM at run time, so they may be read
> reflectively**.